# How to query if an array of values exist in Firebase from android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a static array of dates - `String[] dates = new String[MAX_DAYS]`.

Each date is in the format of `yyyyMMdd` and the array is sorted alphabetically

(e.g. `dates[0] = "20200102"`, `dates[1] = "20200101"`, `dates[2] = "20191231"`, `dates[3] = "20191230"` and so on )

I also have a database (I use Firebase Database) that stores dates (in said format), like this :

```
{   
  "key" : {
    "aaa" : "20191230",
    "bbb" : "20191231",
    "ccc" : "20191231",
    "ddd" : "20191231",
    "eee" : "20200101",
    "fff" : "20200101",
    "ggg" : "20200103"
    }
}
```

I want to check for each value in the `dates` array (minus the first index) if that value appears at least once in the database. (i.e. if all values, but first,  of `dates` exist in database do something, otherwise do something else)

I created a query that fetches only the children under `key` whose value is between `dates[1]` and `dates[dates.length - 1]`:

```
// reference to "key" node
ref.orderByValue().startAt(dates[dates.length - 1]).endAt(dates[1])
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                });
```

What would be the most efficient way of finding out if all values of `dates` exist in the database? Do I simply store each child's value in another array and then loop both arrays? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  List<String> dbDates = new List<>();
  for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    dbDates.add(ds.getValue(String.class);
  }
  for (int i=0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    if (dbDates.contains(dates[i])) {
      System.out.println("Database contains "+dates[i]);
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Database does not contain "+dates[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

So this first converts the snapshots from the database to a list, and then loops over the array you described to check if each of them exists in the database.